# Close policies regarding questions

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I saw [a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6614/693) that was in the process of getting closed.

At least some of the close voters state that it is a shopping question. I have not a problem with that, but I think if we close this question, we have to think about our general closing policies, because we didn't close a lot of similar questions concerning air travel, as I stated in a comment:

> I don't think it is a shopping question. 0x90 is asking for a site
>   where he can search for cheap sea cruises. That's essentially the same
>   as asking for a site to search for air tickets, and we have allowed a
>   lot of such questions.

So basically, what is our guideline here? Should be close all questions that are formulated like this one? Or do we allow such questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm in favour of opening this again, as it's not a direct shopping question - like Royal Caribbean vs Disney cruises or 'what's the best cruise?' - he's trying to find a kayak equivalent for cruises. Sure he can google 'cruise' like @JohnFx suggests, but that won't necessarily find kayak if you google 'airline' - it's the comparison site he's after.

I won't use all my moderator powers to reopen - I'd rather see the community do so, so if you agree, please do go vote to reopen the question - there are already two votes for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a shopping question at all. I voted to reopen. Casting vote oopsie.